# How to solve memory address problems

Tags: memory, byte, mips, memory-address, bit

Can anyone explain how to solve these problems step by step

Assume a 2^24 byte memory.

Assume the memory is byte addressable. What is the lowest address and highest address? How many bits are needed for the address?

Assume the memory is word addressable, with a 16 bit word. What is the lowest address and highest address? How many bits are needed for the address?

Assume the memory is word addressable, with a 32 bit word. What is the lowest address and highest address? How many bits are needed for the address?

Comment: What is the programming problem you're trying to solve? This sounds more like homework from a computer architecture class.

Comment: I am just trying to understand the concept behind solving these kind of problems for my test

Comment: OK, but this isn't about programming, which is what Stack Overflow is for. Maybe cs.stackexchange.com would be better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `byte` is 8 `bits`. If it's `byte`addressable, you can't reference an address by anything other than the start of some `8 bits`. That is, in a `2^2` `byte` memory, you have `4 bytes`. The lowest address starts at `0 bytes`, and the highest address starts at 3 `bytes`. `(0, 1, 2, 3 = 4 bytes total)`

If the bytes are contiguous (they are juxtaposed- touching each other rather than spread out) then you can fit all 4 bytes into a 4 byte memory perfectly.

---

a)

If you have `2^24` `bytes` then you have `2^(24 + 3)` `bits` because you're doing `(2^24 * 2^3) = 2^(24+3)`. Thus you have `134,217,728 total bits`.

The highest address would be one byte before the end, so the address at `2^24 - 1`. Note that it's `2^24 - 1` and not `2^27 - 1` because you are addressing it by `bytes` and not `bits`. Lowest address would be 0.

Lowest address = `0`

Highest address = `2^24 - 1`

---

b)

A `word` just means a grouping of `bytes`. A 1-`byte` `word` is literally the same thing as a `byte`, it just implies that the `word` is some meaningful piece of data, whereas a `byte` is not necessarily a meaningful piece of data.

A `16-bit` `word` == a `2-byte` `word` because 8 `bits` are in a `byte`, thus if you have `2^24` `bytes` available, you only have a total of `2^23` `words`.

Lowest address = `0`

Highest address = max number of words - 1 = `2^23 - 1`.

---

c)

Same thing as with a `4-byte` word instead of 2. Thus:

`2^22 bytes available` to store words.

Lowest address = `0`

Highest address = max number of words - 1 = `2^22 - 1`.

---

Feel free to correct me if you see any errors. Hope I helped.